# Google Trends Feed not working filtered by country (spain)

Tags: feed, google-trends

I have an app that make requests to the google trends feed filtered by the country spain, but since a few days google seems to have an error.

You can request google trends feed by this [url](https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed), and if you add the suffix to the url `?pn=26` you are able to filter to an specific country.

Anybody knows why is this happening or if google has made any change? I am a bit confused, because the rest of countries can be requested successfully.

Here Spain URL feed:

```
https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p26
```

Here some examples of other countries:

```
https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p42 Sweden
https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p46 Switzerland
https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p12 Taiwan
https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p33 Thailand
https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p24 Turkey
https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p35 Ukraine
https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p9 United Kingdom
https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p1 United States
```

Answer (score 1):

Same here!
Even https://trends.google.es/trends/?geo=ES is no longer working.
Check out this thread on Twitter:
https://twitter.com/aleyda/status/1017093832628998144